# Add UTF8 Filter for Servlet

Tags: java, spring, servlets, servlet-filters, spring-java-config

Hi I used Initializer and it worked well.

```
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebAppConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);


        Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic filterRegistration = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter",
                new CharacterEncodingFilter());
        filterRegistration.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        filterRegistration.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        filterRegistration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null,true,"/*");
    }
```

Then I changed it to another:

```
public class Initializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {


    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{WebAppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{WebAppConfig.class};
    }
}
```

But I can't add to it this method:

```
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic filterRegistration = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter",
                new CharacterEncodingFilter());
        filterRegistration.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        filterRegistration.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        filterRegistration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
    }
```

Because the application falls.
What am I doing wrong? How to add this filter to a new Initializer to force it work?
Thank you.

Comment: What do you thing the `getServletFilters` method does? Override this method and return an instance of the filter(s) you want to add.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    protected FilterRegistration.Dynamic registerServletFilter(ServletContext servletContext, Filter filter) {

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic filterRegistration =     servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter",
                new CharacterEncodingFilter());
        filterRegistration.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        filterRegistration.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        filterRegistration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");

        return super.registerServletFilter(servletContext, filter);
    }
```